# PHP how to convert date from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-conversion

I am using MySQL and php.  When I get a date from MySQL it is in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. Once I get this string, how can I convert it to format of example `Jan 2 2013` in php?

I tried

```
date("M j Y", mysql_result($recordset, $i, 'date_started'));
```

using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php as a reference, but I get some weird date as the output.

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: you could use the mysql function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP `date()` method needs a timestamp, so convert your mysql date string to a timestamp first using [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
date("M j Y", strtotime(mysql_result($recordset, $i, 'date_started')));
```

Or better yet, format your date in your mysql query directly using [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). You don't really even need PHP to do this.

Comment: Has no one heard of DateTime?

Comment: @Rottingham sure, but strtotime() is just simpler in this particular case. especially since you can keep it inline, and not need to break up the code if you don't want to.

Comment: True, I still tend to lean on DateTime because once I have the object, I can do much more with it in a 'pretty fashion', like $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));

Comment: @Rottingham certainly, and I push DateTime also as good OO development in general. just trying to answer the specific question here with the simplest answer.

Comment: Not criticizing you Js, good answer! :-)

Comment: There is a min wait time before you can mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using the DateTime wrapper gives you functionality that is worth having. To convert from mysql Format, simple follow this pattern.

```
$mysqlDate = '2014-01-01';
$myDate = new DateTime($mysqlDate);

echo $myDate->format('M j Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use date_format in mysql like this

`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %y') //%b is the short name of a month`